# Constante contendo Array (matriz)

Tags: php, array, constantes

Quando eu tento definir uma constante como sendo uma Array dá erro.

```
define('COLORS', ['red', 'blue', 'green']);
```

Existe alguma forma de definir uma Array no valor de uma constante?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Antes do PHP 5.6:**
É possível fazer uma gambiarra utilizando as funções `serialize()` e `unserialize()`:

```
define('COLORS', serialize(['red', 'blue', 'green']));
unserialize(COLORS);
```

**Apartir do PHP 5.6:**
Comforme [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) mencionou, a documentação do PHP nos diz isso:

> Até o PHP 5.6, somente dados escalares (boolean, integer, float e string) podem ser colocados em constantes. A partir do PHP 5.6, é possível também utilizar um array como valor de constantes. É permitido o uso de um resource (recurso) como valor de constante, mas deve ser evitado já que pode causar resultados não esperados.

É possível definir uma constante contendo diretamente uma array dessa forma:

```
const COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
```

NOTA: Fiz alguns testes e percebi que os valores na Array definida em constantes também deve ser do tipo *escalar* ou outra Array. Ex.:
 Isso NÃO é permitido: `const CLASSES = ['anyClass' => new anyClass()];`

**Somente apartir do PHP 7.0** que tem previsão pra sair em Novembro de 2015, que será possível definir uma Array diretamente na função `define()` dessa forma:

```
define('COLORS', ['red', 'blue', 'green']);
```

Answer (score 3):

[O manual responde](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.syntax.php):

> Até o PHP 5.6, somente dados escalares (boolean, integer, float e string) podem ser colocados em constantes. A partir do PHP 5.6, é possível também utilizar um array como valor de constantes. É permitido o uso de um resource (recurso) como valor de constante, mas deve ser evitado já que pode causar resultados não esperados.

Comment: Posso adaptar uma resposta no SO gringo aqui? É possivel sim definir "uma array" antes do PHP 5.6, mas somente com o uso de uma função.

Comment: À vontade. Se quiser editar minha resposta, eu transformo em "wiki comunitário". Se preferir, pode postar uma resposta separada.

Comment: Sou novo no SO. Não sei oq é uma Wiki Comunitário... Já respondi minha pergunta.

Comment: Ficou muito boa a sua resposta! Esclarecendo, Wiki Comunitário é uma marcação que podemos fazer na resposta pra indicar que ela é colaborativa. Ela passa a ser de autoria coletiva, e ninguém ganha pontos pelos votos que ela receber.

Answer (score -2):

```
$colors = array("red","blue","green") will be just fine.
```

Comment: Eu quero uma constante... Não uma variável...